# Why Tailwind CSS classes is not working after restarting my PC?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, tailwind-css

The Project with React + Tailwind was running perfect but when I restarted the project after shutdown my PC.
Tailwind classes are not working. Do I need to install or start anything for Tailwind too just like react server npm start?

I tried
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
and
npm install postcss@latest

Comment: please provide a sample code to reproduce the issue